# Change the scope of DLFileEntry of Liferay6.1

Tags: liferay

I have many files that have been added by one user. Now I need to show these file to all user (not only to who that added). I try to make an update directly to db (ResourcePermissin scope = 2). But nothing change..

How can resolve this? (By code or query on db)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can update the permissions for the files and give `VIEW` permission for `Guest` Role or give `VIEW` permission to `USER` role if you want to show the files only to logged-in Users.

Overview Steps:

1. Fetch the files
2. Apply the permissions to the files
3. Save the updated files

An idea as to how liferay updates the permissions can be taken from [`portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/portlet_configuration/edit_permissions_algorithm_5_to_6.jsp`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/portlet_configuration/edit_sharing.jsp) and

Comment: I tried with resource-actions xml. I try to give to the portlet document and media lib (20) the VIEW capability on DLFileEntry, Shortcut and EntryType. But don't work.  For me is a good thing to do VIEW permission for Guest Role. But is possibile to do this directly on DB? I think that actionIDs need an update, but I don't understand what meaning. What's mean an actionId = 127 ??  (ActionKeys constants file have string values, not number)

Comment: Your `resource-actions.xml` won't work since the data is already thre in the database. Liferay uses bitwise calculation to store permissions, you can create a portlet and run the code to update the file permisssions for all the files.